Reorder ordinal variables in table
I am a super beginner, I am using Rstudio for a University project and I got stuck with the following problem.
I created a table as follows
> table(Nationality,Q11)
           Q11
Nationality A little bit Absolutely not Absolutely yes Fairly
  I                4              0              1      0
  J                3              0              0      2
  S                3              1              0      1

I would need to reorder the Q11 as follows:
absolutely not, a little bit, fairly, absolutely yes
As a table i could not find a solution.
I tried with data.frame and levels:
data.frame(Nationality, Q11)
df_FC_N_Q11 <- data.frame(Nationality, Q11)
levels(df_FC_N_Q11$Q11)
levels(df_FC_N_Q11$Nationality)

but the result was as follow:
> df_FC_N_Q11 <- data.frame(Nationality, Q11)
> levels(df_FC_N_Q11$Q11)
NULL
> levels(df_FC_N_Q11$Nationality)
NULL


To reorder Q11, coerce to factor with levels set to the desired order before calling table.
Q11_levels <- c("Absolutely not", "A little bit", "Fairly", "Absolutely yes")
df_FC_N_Q11$Q11 <- factor(df_FC_N_Q11$Q11, levels = Q11_levels)

with(df_FC_N_Q11, table(Nationality, Q11))
#>            Q11
#> Nationality Absolutely not A little bit Fairly Absolutely yes
#>           I             10           14      8              9
#>           J             10            8      4              7
#>           S              6           12      9              3

Created on 2024-10-26 with reprex v2.1.1

Data
Q11 <- c("A little bit", "Absolutely not", "Absolutely yes", "Fairly")
Nationality <- c("I", "J", "S")

n <- 1e2
set.seed(2024)
df_FC_N_Q11 <- data.frame(
  Nationality = sample(Nationality, n, TRUE), 
  Q11 = sample(Q11, n, TRUE)
)

Created on 2024-10-26 with reprex v2.1.1
